# Rust - implementing trait for Deref: the parameter type `T` may not live long enough

Tags: rust, traits, lifetime, dereference

I have a trait:

```
trait Foo {
    fn bar(&self) -> Cow<str>;
}
```

And I want to implement it for any type that implements `Deref` with a target of a type that implements `Foo`. Basically:

```
impl<T: Foo, D: std::ops::Deref<Target = T>> Foo for D {
    fn bar(&self) -> Cow<str> {
        <T as Foo>::bar(std::ops::Deref::deref(self))
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this gives the error `the parameter type T may not live long enough`.

My understanding is that `T` could have a reference within it that has a short lifetime, and the lifetime bound of the return value of `Cow<str>` is linked to the lifetime of `&self` due to lifetime elision, which would cause problems.

I'm not sure how I can fix this, since I'm not able to bound any of the lifetimes in `bar`. I can try to make sure `T` lives as long as `&self`, but this doesn't work.

```
impl<'a, T: Foo + 'a, D: std::ops::Deref<Target = T>> Foo for D {
    fn bar(&'a self) -> Cow<'a, str> {
        <T as Foo>::bar(std::ops::Deref::deref(self))
    }
}
```

I get the error `method not compatible with trait` since the lifetimes don't match the trait defenition anymore. I've tried all sorts of different ways of adding lifetime bounds and I always get one of those two errors.

I am able to implement `Foo` for a specific type that implements `Deref`:

```
impl<T: Foo> Foo for Box<T> {
    fn bar(&self) -> Cow<str> {
        <T as Foo>::bar(self)
    }
}
```

I'm not sure why that works but the original example doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Box` version works because of the deref coercion the compiler will do when it sees a reference and expects a different reference.
You can use the same mechanic when using a generic implementor of `Deref` to ensure that it `Deref`s to an owned type you can simply add a `'static` lifetime bound on `T` like this:

```rust
impl<T: Foo + 'static, D: std::ops::Deref<Target = T>> Foo for D {
    fn bar(&self) -> Cow<str> {
        <T as Foo>::bar(self)
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f4859e9bb0ec89249d9d7a26024beb58)

Note: there is rarely a need to call methods of `std::ops` traits directly, they're all just the methods behind Rusts operators, `deref` for example is the method behind unary `*`

---

Update:

Since there is an additional requirement that `T` might not be static we have to thread through the lifetime like you tried in your second example, like the error you're getting suggest you have to adjust the trait to take a lifetime as well:

```rust
use std::borrow::Cow;
trait Foo<'a> {
    fn bar(&self) -> Cow<'a, str>;
}

impl<'a, T: Foo<'a>, D: std::ops::Deref<Target = T>> Foo<'a> for D {
    fn bar(&self) -> Cow<'a, str> {
        <T as Foo>::bar(self)
    }
}

struct S<'a> {
    val: &'a str,
}

impl<'a> Foo<'a> for S<'a> {
    fn bar(&self) -> Cow<'a, str> {
        todo!()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let val = String::from("test");
    let s = S { val: &val }; // error: `val` does not live long enough
    let b = Box::new(s);
    let cow = Foo::bar(&b); // argument requires that `val` is borrowed for `'static`
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to avoid using a `'static` bound since I thought the meaning was similar to the `'static` lifetime, but that makes a lot of sense when you explain it as just meaning an owned type. I was explicit with the deref so that I could know exactly what was going on and that I wasn't missing anything, but now that i've go it working ill remove it. Thanks for the help:)

Comment: Actually, I just realized a problem-- I do need `T` to be able to have non-static references. If I try to use a `Box` holding a type that has `&str` in it as `Foo`, it obviously gives some lifetime error due to the `'static` bound. But if I go back to the manual implementation of `Foo` for `Box<Foo>`, it does work. So its seemingly possible, I just can find any equivalent blanket implementation. I still don't understand why the blanket implementation and the one for `Box` are different, and why the latter works.

Comment: Hmm but Box<&T> can be coerced to a `&T` without a problem. It should work for all (smart) pointer types, and others shouldn't implement `Deref` in the first place. Can you share an example where this fails? @CameronDelong

Comment: Yeah ofc. [Here](https://pastebin.com/bnJLjT7P) is the example with the blanket implementation, which gives an error as shown in the comments in the example. And [here](https://pastebin.com/FHbrqWxq) is with just the impl for box, which compiles without errors. I'd like the blanket implementation to work for any type that implements `Foo`, not just ones without non-static references. @cafce25